# Unable to use Static Cells in UITableViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview

I need to use static cells in my app. I am using Xcode 5 and testing thins on iOS 7 simulator (iPad).

I dragged out a new UITableViewController in storyboard and set the tableview's cells to be static. Then I added a Label to the first cell to check if static cells are working. I ran the app and I got blank cells (dynamic form).

Then I added a class that implements the datasource and delegate methods of a table and attached it to the controller in storyboard. Yet, nothing happened. Finally, I embedded it in a UINavigationController and still, I get plain blank cells like the one below:

[image: Table Cells]

Could you tell me whats going wrong here, i.e., why wont my static cells show up!?

Regards

Comment: Is your TableViewController marked as "Is Initial View Controller"?

Comment: Yes @Eugen it's marked as Initial VC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use static cells you dont need the datasource. so delete all methods that belongs to datasource, such as cellForRowAtIndexPath. After deleting the methods your label should appear.

Comment: Damn. How could I forget something so silly. Thanks nevertheless :)